# How do I upgrade (copy settings) from Cura 2.5 to Cura 2.6?

Tags: ultimaker-cura

On my Mac I've got two versions of Cura installed, in `/Applications/Cura250` and `/Applications/Cura262`.

How can I copy my printer and profile settings from Cura 2.5 to Cura 2.6?

Comment: Ya got me - I upgraded and IIRC there was some option to click to import settings, or maybe they just got imported automatically.  DId you check that your setups are *not* available?

Comment: Yep... only shows a default printer in 2.6.  I'd be content knowing if I could copy some config files from 2.5 to 2.6.  Or maybe this will be a feature in 2.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Ultimaker Forum](https://ultimaker.com/en/community/50751-how-to-copy-machine-and-profile-settings-from-cura-25-to-cura-26?page=1):

- Launch Cura 2.6 and go to Help -> Show Configuration folder. Now close Cura.
- These are the configuration files for Cura 2.6. They are in a folder named 2.6.
- On OSX, the configuration files for Cura 2.5 are one folder up (not in a folder named 2.5). You can copy files from that parent folder into the folder named 2.6, and Cura should update them as needed the next time it is started.

Comment: side note: Cura still forced me to create a new printer via an uncloseable dialog window, even though my previous (non-network) printer showed up in the list afterwards as well. The trick otherwise works great +1

Answer (score 3):

Hope this is all you need.
From [the release notes page](https://ultimaker.com/en/products/cura-software/release-notes)

> Cura 2.6 - June 20, 2017 Local version folders. When installing a new
>   version of Cura, a new local directory will be created to make it easy
>   to access old configuration folders and return to old settings if
>   necessary.

So if you know where your current 2.5 config directory is, you should be all set.

Comment: So... How do you copy the settings? Move the files from one folder to the other?

Comment: @TomvanderZanden I wouldn't move the files, but copy them. Once everything works fine and you're happy with the new version, feel free to remove the old settings folder.